# Rewrite rules does not work on new server

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting

I am creating a new internal system, and I based my rewrite rules based on previous and existing projects.
They consist of a GUI in the root, API folder for API and at times a folder with graphics for emails.
On top of that they had a "dev" folder, with the same inside (api folder e.g.) for testing. This is being replaced for a new separate dev-domains in new systems.
Some have more, but this is the simple way I have for now. I am not an expert in this field.

So, I went ahead a used a previous web.config file, see below.

However, I had issues with getting the graphics (api/template/gfx.gif), so I created the save folder structure (dev/api). It will give me a hello-world-index.html file (in dev), so that part works.
But calling dev/api/test/ping does not work. The api/test/ping does work.
Calling DEV/api/test/ping causes error 500.

The system works with GUI and API, but not on dev despite using the same rules as for other projects.

The API is made .Net 6

Could it be some setting on the server side?
This project is a new server. There might be differences

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Forces HTTPS" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Dev Route" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^dev(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/dev/api(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/dev/index.html" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^.*$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api/template(.*)" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api(.*)" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/dev(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html?r=error" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Use FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and you might be able to help yourself.

Comment: For us, we don't know your actual project structure and cannot reproduce your problem. As lex Li said, the best way is to use [Failed Request Tracing Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules), it will provide the key error and warning, which will help you to identify the problem.